# How to attach an audio with every contact to phonebook in IOS

Tags: ios, contacts, voice, recording

I have two screen.

"Screen 1" where user enter New contact information and save it to Phonebook.

"Screen 2" after saving contact, all contacts are displaying in this screen in table view.

Now every thing is working fine and in "screen 1" user can also record his voice for speaking contact names like "John" but i have a problem that i dont know that how i can save that recorded voice with contact in phonebook

so that when user taps on any contact name in screen 2, it should speak that recorded voice.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I can add all contact information using PHONEBOOK interface in IOS but i dont know how i can attach audio to every contact in PHONEBOOK.
Only i need to remember the audio file name of every contact separately so that i call that audio on TAP on every contact name.

Is there need of database or any thing else ???

Answer (score 0):

I would use a database where you store every reference to your contact objects (or even the whole contacts) and add a field that is "audioFilePath" where you store the audio path.

That audiopath would simply be the path to the audio file that you save in screen one, in, say, `Documents/AudioFiles/name_lastname_audio.wav`, for example.

Follow a CoreData guide like this awesome one : [TutsPlus Core Data from scratch!](http://code.tutsplus.com/series/core-data-from-scratch--cms-653)

Or simply use an sqlite3 database and fill it yourself (maybe using a sexy wrapper like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)).

Either is fine but remember this :

Storing a lot of entries and keeping it usually requires a database.
You can't/don't want to store big files in a database, so keep their path instead.

Comment: make sure to upvote/mark as correct if you found this useful \o/ !

Comment: sorry i dont have enough reputations to Vote UP

Comment: One thing more when i'll save the path of that audio in DB than how i can differentiate the exact path for each contact because in screen 2 all contact are displaying in TableView and when user taps on any contact than it will play that recording and now at this point how i will get the exact path for contact.
Because if i give that recording name with its contact's first name than there may be many other contacts having same first name etc

Comment: You could save the row id in the filename to make it unique, and each contact always has a unique row id. A mix of first+last name also worldometers and is less likely to generate doubles. Phone Numbers are also unique.

Comment: You can also find unique id generators on internet as iOS frameworks. You can store the id as a column and use that same unique id for filename

Comment: Actually i am making app for LowVision Persons they don't enter all information for creating new contacts and for that may be they only enter phone number and record their voice and save the contact so here if i save the audio with the phone number than later on may be they changed the phone number than on Tap i'll search out the audio with the "file name  = phoneNumber" so here it will say no audio found.